# sum array with condition in another array with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following python code to sum an array with condition in another array

```
sum=0
for i in range(grp_num):
    if lower_bounds[i] > 0:
        sum = sum + histo1[i]
```

I believe numpy equivalent would be `np.where(lower_bounds>0, histo1,0).sum()`
But the numpy method adds up everything in histo1 (ignoring requirement that lower_bounds>0).  Why?  Or is there another way to do this?  Thanks.

Comment: `histo1[lower_bounds>0].sum()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is admittedly guesswork, but the only explanation I can think of for your `np.where(lower_bounds>0, histo1,0).sum()` returning the full sum is

- you are on Python2
- lower_bounds is a list, not an array

on Python2:

```
[1, 2] > 0
True
```

meaning that your numpy line will broadcast its first argument and always pick from histo1, never from 0. Note that the alternative formulation that was suggested in the comments `histo1[lower_bounds>0].sum()` will not work either (it will return `histo1[1]`) in this situation.

The solution. Explicitly convert lower_bounds to an array

```
 np.where(np.array(lower_bounds)>0, histo1, 0)
```

Btw. on Python3 you would get an exception

```
[1, 2] > 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
```

Comment: You were right (about Python 2 and list)!  As a beginner to Python, I was not discipline about data structures.  Thanks.